# Pandas - How to split a string column into several columns, by the index of specific characters?

Tags: python, pandas, string, indexing, split

I want to extract the user ID from a string column called "filename", and create a new ID column,
based on the index of specific character in the original string.

**Two examples for the string in "filename", with ID of 2 or 3 digits:**

1. filename = ID**100**session1neg_emotions_rating.csv  ---> ID = 100
2. filename =ID**21**session2neu_emotions_rating.csv   ---> ID = 21

I tried this -

```
df['ID '] = df.filename.str[2:**4**]
```

but I couldn't find the end index of the ID for the slice per row (it 3 or 4, depends on the length of the ID as 2 or 3 digits).

finding the index of "s" after each row in the data frame will solve my problem.
The simple option didn't work for me -

```
s_index = df.filename.str.index("s")
```

(I also tried some split option, but I don't have a specific character such as comma, to split by)

Thanks a lot!
sorry if it's a duplication of a previous question

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regex with `str.extract`:

```
s_index = df.filename.str.extract("^ID(\d+)")
```

As integers:

```
s_index = df.filename.str.extract("^ID(\d+)").astype(int)
```

[Regex101 explanation](https://regex101.com/r/rwFyEr/1)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to regex which is probably the best answer is to use `split` first on 'session' and grabbing the very first element and then another `split` grabbing the last element:

```
df['ID'] =  df.filename.str.split('session').str[0].str.split('ID').str[1]
```

Comment: thanks!  
I get this error message:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split

Comment: Can you try it again please @omer? I have modified the answer slightly.

Comment: It work snow, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Please don't forget to upvote all the answers that are helpful to encourage participation, and tick one answer to accept it. Thanks again.